# How to encourage an aquarium plant to carpet on it's own?

Tags: aquarium, fish, aquatic-plants, maintenance

I have a small 10 gallon planted aquarium with *Staurogyne repens* as the main plant. My long-term goal is to have the *S. repens* cover most of the substrate. The substrate in my aquarium is organic soil covered with [Eco-Complete](https://www.petco.com/shop/en/petcostore/product/eco-complete-planted-black-aquarium-substrate) substrate. I've had the *S. repens* in the aquarium for more than 6 months and it seems to be growing just fine, but it won't spread across the substrate on it's own. I have been trimming and manually propagating cuttings to spread it around. Is there any way I can encourage the *S. repens* to carpet across the substrate on its own?

(CO<sub>2</sub> is not an option)